# how to filter all the elements of the list in R? but the filter will use the mean of each element so the condition will change for each element

Tags: r, list, filter

I have a dataset with temperature data for each day, so i  grouped them by date. In the end i have a list with dataframes for each day. Now what i want to do is i want to filter by a range all these dataframes. the filter is the mean value of temperature for that day(dataframe) +- 0.5°C.
But the problem is that each dataframe in the list has a different mean value (I hope im clear).
So i want to filter by the mean values of a column but this mean changes for every dataframe.

How can i solve this problem.
I'm an amateur in R so anything is helpful. Thank you in advance

This is a short version of the my list

```
structure(list(structure(list(Date = structure(c(1646434800, 
1646434800, 1646434800, 1646434800, 1646434800, 1646434800, 1646434800, 
1646434800, 1646434800, 1646434800), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), V4 = c(0.875, 0.5, 0.1875, -0.1875, -0.5, -0.8125, 
-1.125, -1.375, -1.625, -1.875)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(Date = structure(c(1646521200, 
1646521200, 1646521200, 1646521200, 1646521200, 1646521200, 1646521200, 
1646521200, 1646521200, 1646521200, 1646521200), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), V4 = c(3.75, 3.75, 3.6875, 3.6875, 3.6875, 3.6875, 
3.6875, 3.625, 3.625, 3.625, 3.625)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(Date = structure(c(1646607600, 
1646607600, 1646607600, 1646607600, 1646607600, 1646607600, 1646607600, 
1646607600, 1646607600, 1646607600, 1646607600), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), V4 = c(3.6875, 3.6875, 3.6875, 3.6875, 3.6875, 3.625, 
3.625, 3.625, 3.625, 3.625, 3.625)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))), ptype = structure(list(Date = structure(numeric(0), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), V4 = numeric(0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = integer(0)), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))
```

Comment: Hi! To better help you solve your problem, please share a sample of the data using one of the methods described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please don't share data using images. `dput()` is the gold standard for sharing (small) samples of data.

Comment: did i add my list correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in several ways. Suppose `mydata` is the list that you provided in the question.

1. In `dplyr` you can bind the rows of all the data frames in `mydata` first to create a single data frame, and then group them by the `Date`, and then apply the filter to each group. The result is a data frame.

```
do.call(rbind, mydata) %>% 
        group_by(Date) %>% filter((V4 <= mean(V4) + 0.5) & 
                                  (V4 >= mean(V4)-0.5)) 

# A tibble: 25 x 2
# Groups:   Date [3]
# Date                    V4
# <dttm>               <dbl>
#   1 2022-03-05 06:00:00 -0.188
# 2 2022-03-05 06:00:00 -0.5  
# 3 2022-03-05 06:00:00 -0.812
# 4 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.75 
# 5 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.75 
# 6 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.69 
# 7 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.69 
# 8 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.69 
# 9 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.69 
# 10 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.69 
# ... with 15 more rows
```

2. In R `base` you can define your function that filters a single data frame, and then apply the function to `mydata`. The result is a list of data frames.

```
myfilter <- function(df) {
  cond <- (df$V4 <= mean(df$V4 + 0.5) & (df$V4 >= mean(df$V4) - 0.5))
  result <- df[cond,]
  return(result)
}

lapply(mydata, myfilter)
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# Date                    V4
# <dttm>               <dbl>
#   1 2022-03-05 06:00:00 -0.188
# 2 2022-03-05 06:00:00 -0.5  
# 3 2022-03-05 06:00:00 -0.812
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 11 x 2
# Date                   V4
# <dttm>              <dbl>
#   1 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.75
# 2 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.75
# 3 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.69
# 4 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.69
# 5 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.69
# 6 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.69
# 7 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.69
# 8 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.62
# 9 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.62
# 10 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.62
# 11 2022-03-06 06:00:00  3.62
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 11 x 2
# Date                   V4
# <dttm>              <dbl>
#   1 2022-03-07 06:00:00  3.69
# 2 2022-03-07 06:00:00  3.69
# 3 2022-03-07 06:00:00  3.69
# 4 2022-03-07 06:00:00  3.69
# 5 2022-03-07 06:00:00  3.69
# 6 2022-03-07 06:00:00  3.62
# 7 2022-03-07 06:00:00  3.62
# 8 2022-03-07 06:00:00  3.62
# 9 2022-03-07 06:00:00  3.62
# 10 2022-03-07 06:00:00  3.62
# 11 2022-03-07 06:00:00  3.62
```